# Npm dependencies were not found during npm run dev

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-mix

Parts of my app are built using VueJS. The complete app is built on top of the Laravel framework, so I use Laravel Mix to compile my css/js-assets. To gather a better overview, I've put parts of my application in seperated packages, e.g.:

- app
- bootstrap
- config
- ...
- packages

  - catalog
  - resources
  - js

    - Components
    - CatalogComponentA.vue
    - ...
    - catalog.js
- ...
- resources

  - assets
  - js
  - VueComponents

    - ComponentA.vue
    - ...
  - app.js

Running npm locally (either in Homestead/Vagrant or under my OS) works absolutely fine. Deploying it to my webserver results in an error saying that the dependencies were not found:

```
*/home/forge/my-domain.com/packages/catalog/resources/js/Components/AddressAutoComplete in ./packages/catalog/resources/js/catalog.js
*/home/forge/my-domain.com/packages/catalog/resources/js/Components/Vehicle in ./packages/catalog/resources/js/catalog.js
*/home/forge/my-domain.com/packages/catalog/resources/js/Components/VehicleList in ./packages/catalog/resources/js/catalog.js
...
```

I've the same version of npm on all systems. I've tried to re-install my npm packages and tried `Vue.component('my-component', require('./path-to-my-component'))`

My `catalog.js` uses components from its own sub-directory:

```
require('./../../../../resources/assets/js/app_bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

require('./../../../../resources/assets/js/coreComponents');

// Components
Vue.component('address-autocomplete', require(__dirname + '/Components/AddressAutoComplete'));
Vue.component('vehicle-list', require(__dirname + '/Components/VehicleList'));
Vue.component('vehicle', require(__dirname + '/Components/Vehicle'));
...
```

My webpack.mix.js is configured like this:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

let cssPath = 'public/css';
let jsPath = 'public/js';

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', jsPath)
        .js('packages/catalog/resources/js/catalog.js', jsPath)
        .sass('packages/catalog/resources/sass/catalog.scss', cssPath)
        .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', cssPath)
        .sourceMaps()
        .version();
} else {
    mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', jsPath)
        .js('packages/catalog/resources/js/catalog.js', jsPath)
        .sass('packages/catalog/resources/sass/catalog.scss', cssPath)
        .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', cssPath)
        .sourceMaps();
}
```

Comment: first run `npm run install` and then `npm run dev`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I've tried it. And this is exactly what happens during my deployment.

Comment: Do you have package.json file?
I cannot see that in your directory structure

Comment: Seconding the `package.json` comment. If you don't have this at the root of your directory, NPM will not know what node modules to install.

Comment: Yes I've the package.json file. ``npm update/install`` works fine. All dependencies are installed. What fails is the ``npm run dev`` command..

Comment: run `npm audit fix`

Comment: This doesn't work @WimPruiksma. It fails to load the needed Vue-Components

Comment: IF it's working locally fine then the server paths are diffrent or something. I don't think it's a problem with npm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem were the file-endings. The components which could not be loaded had an uppercase file extension (`.Vue` instead of `.vue`). Because my server OS is case sensitive, it couldn't load the modules..